# Finding any text in a column - Then moving other numbers beside the found text

Tags: excel, vba

So as the title says I am trying to search Col C and if text/number is found then move text from another cell to Col D

So to put it more simply

EG: There is some text in C10 - So I want to copy text from I8 to D10 (new data is always two Rows up and Col I)

Ive been playing around with this VBA code

```
Dim find As String
Dim findcell As Range

FindString = "*" 
'Not sure how to find anything - But if I put a string that actually is in the sheet then it moves the example same one to Col D

For Each findcell In Range(ActiveSheet.Range("C1"), ActiveSheet.Range("C250").End(xlUp)).Cells
    If InStr(findcell, FindString) > 0 Then findcell.Offset(, 1) = FindString
Next findcell
```

Any help / advice would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim findcell As Range

For Each findcell In Range(ActiveSheet.Range("C3"), ActiveSheet.Range("C250").End(xlUp)).Cells
    If Len(findcell) > 0 Then findcell.Offset(0, 1) = findcell.Offset(-2, 6)
Next findcell
```

But of course this will only work from row 3 and onwards as you say that the new data is always two rows up.

Comment: Could I ask you for another modification? I was wondering how I would add the letter A or B to cell E (My data is in Lots of 2) ie C10 has some data, then so does C11, then nothing till C25 / C26 etc. I want to put the A in E10 and B in E11 (but not sure how to check if text above / below ) Hope that makes sense

Comment: My new code: (Just added one line, which appears to be working) For Each findtext In Range(ActiveSheet.Range("C3"), ActiveSheet.Range("C250").End(xlUp)).Cells
        If Len(findtext) > 0 Then findtext.Offset(0, 1) = findtext.Offset(-2, 7)
        If Len(findtext) > 0 Then findtext.Offset(0, 2) = findtext.Offset(0, 1) + findtext.Offset(0, 0)
    Next findtext I added a new line (which as you would tell from reading it just adds up the Total) -